# Unable to retrieve the selected value of a dynamically populated dropdown in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am totally new to Ruby on Rails, I was following some tutorials and developed a small CRUD application. In a form I have a drop down which was previously filled with hard coded values but now I have populated it with the values retrieved from database which works fine, but the trouble is I intend to get the selected value of the dropdown but instead of that I end up getting the id of that value, I know I am doing something logically wrong, I have did some research but was unable to come across a solution that fulfilled my requirement.

Here is my controller action,

```
def new
@list=CategoryType.all
end
```

Here is the dropdown within the form:

```
<%= f.label :maincategory %>
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@list, 'id','maincategory') %>
<%= f.select :maincategory, options %>
```

And this is the action getting back the parameters from the form in the controller:

```
   private
   def category_params
     params.require(:category).permit(:name, :maincategory)
   end
```

And this action saves it in the database:

```
 def create
        @category= Category.new(category_params)

    if @category.save
     redirect_to @category
  else
     render 'new'
  end
end
```

Instead of maincategory id is being saved in the database, i am totally new to ROR, would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `name` attribute in your category_types table,if so change this line `<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@list, 'id','maincategory') %>` to `<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@list, 'id','name') %>`

Comment: no i only have maincategory in the category_type table and i want to retrieve that(from the dropdown) as i submit the form but instead it stores the id in anther table of the database, I want the selected maincategory to be retreived and stored the in the database, cannot figure out a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Why would you save the `maincategory` as a string ?

I suppose in your `Category` model, you should have a `belongs_to :category_type`.
I think it's better to save the `CategoryType` id of your `maincategory` object.

This way, you have the correct relation between your category and its type. Therefore, you could have the CategoryType of your category with this command : `@category.category_type.name`, if you want to retrieve the name of your record, as your data relation would be correct.

Let me know if I misunderstood something !

Comment: What you said actually made a lot of sense and it sounds logical, I am gonna add the relationship between the two definitely thanks for that and yes the id would be a good choice for that relationship in the other table, its just for learning that's why I have chosen string as data type, just wanted to know if I can have the maincategory that appears in the dropdown (coming from another table) in my parameters and store that in another table, its just for learning this application, thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Comment: Glad I could help. (it's actually advice I received not so long ago, which made a lot of sense as well !).

Comment: thanks a lot, but is there anyway to access the 'maincategory' specifically to store in the database? just wanted to know that.

Comment: I am not familiar with the dropdown or front issue. But in the controller, as you get the category_type.id, you could populate the maincategory with the category_type.name easily.